# Why is the mean curvature usually denoted by $H$?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, riemannian-geometry, math-history

Soft question. For surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$ (for example), there are two relevant curvatures: the Gaussian curvature $K$, and the mean curvature $H$. Thinking here, I realized that while calling the Gaussian curvature $K$ makes sense (since in German curvature is *Krümmung*), I have no idea why is the mean curvature denoted by $H$.

Is there any historical reason, or some word in German (or any other language) I'm missing?

Comment: I wonder if it's because of the relation with the harmonic mean?

Comment: But the mean curvature is the arithmetic mean of the principal curvatures, not the harmonic mean. Maybe some relation with the fact that an isothermic immersion is minimal if and only if it is harmonic?

Comment: It's the reciprocal of the harmonic mean of the radii of curvature. It was just a guess anyway, I have no real reason to expect that to be the reason.

Comment: One thing to note is that the components of the second fundamental form are traditionally denoted $E,F$, and $G$. I think this goes back to Gauss himself.

Comment: might consider re-asking in [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)